# How to hide Nav component in admin page in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a reactjs.

**I want to hide my navbar component in admin page. There are plenty of answers in SO but none of them is worked for me. please guide me how to do that**

- I tried that outlet one but didn't got my solution and also tried that  solotion but it is not working in new react version*

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Views/Header';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Views/Home';
import Contact from './Views/Contact';
import About from './Views/About';
import Footer from './Views/Footer';
import Login from './Views/Login';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import UserDashboard from './Views/UserDashboard';
import AllData from './Views/AllData';
import AdminHome from './Admin/AdminHome';
import AdminLogin from './Admin/AdminLogin';
import Error from './Views/Error';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
import Logout from './components/Logout';
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { reducer, initialState } from "../src/reducer/UseReducer"
import AboutUser from './components/AboutUser';
import UpdateUser from './components/UpdateUser';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'




export const userContext = createContext()

function App() {
  <ToastContainer />

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  return (
    <>

      <userContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
        

          <Header />
          <Routes>
            
              
            <Route exact path="/(login)" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
            <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
            <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path='/dashboard' element={<UserDashboard />} />
            <Route path='/alldata' element={<AllData />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />

            <Route path='/adminlogin' element={<AdminLogin />} />            
            <Route path='/admin' element={<AdminHome />} />
            <Route path='/blog' element={<Blog />} />
            <Route path='/logout' element={<Logout />} />
            <Route path='/AboutUser' element={<AboutUser />} />
            <Route path='/updateuser' element={<UpdateUser />} />


          </Routes>
          <Footer />




      </userContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please apply check like blow

```
{(!user.isAdmin?<Display here>:null)}
```

Comment: where to apply this and what is user and isAdmin?

Comment: Where you want to hide and show the navbar component.

Comment: I want to hide my navbar component in <Adminhome/> and <adminlogin/> !!

Comment: You want to hide when the user has role admin you need to apply to check on user role and show and hide by !admin?<Show NavBar>:null

Comment: on user <adminlogin/> you need to verify by the route whether the route belongs to admin login.

Comment: I don't need to check the user role...i only need to hide navbar from AdminHome and AdminLogin componrnt ( acc. to above code) ...is that possible?

Comment: AdminHome component that means admin user is loggedin?

Comment: AdminLogin component where the user is going to log in?

Comment: yes u r correct!!

Comment: OK, then on the AdminHome component you have the admin user object apply check to hide the NavBar component.

Comment: And AdminLogin you have some route difference e.g /admin or /admin/login etc just get the current route and check that component is AdminLogin then hide <NavBar>

Comment: ok...can u add an answer!